# «По Иванову(,) нужно сделать так...» Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Верна ли пунктуация?
«По М.А. Иванову(,) нужно сделать так...»

Answer (score -1):

Не вижу необходимости в запятой. Может в более полном контексте что-то прояснится, но вряд ли.

Через четыре года вопрос всплыл. ))) Ясности не добавило.
Видимо дело в том, что подобные предложения в научном стиле не трактуются как источник сообщения.

"По Иванову, бактерии в подобных условиях не размножаются" - тут вопроса нет. По Иванову - источник сообщения.

"Кесарево сечение(,) по Иванову(,) производится в исключительных случаях".
Если это "согласно исследования Иванова" то еще можно (и нужно, нааерное) считать источником сообщения.
Но вот если именно "по методу"

> В восемь с половиной часов вечера произведена первая в Европе операция по профессору Преображенскому: под хлороформенным наркозом удалены яичники Шарика...

(МАБ)

> В ночь после операции: грозные повторные падения пульса. Ожидание смертного исхода. Громадные дозы камфары по Преображенскому.

Там же.

Ну какие ж тут запятые? Так вот именно в этом смысле обычно идет текст в научных статьях "по Пупкину". Так что я бы не горячился.

Comment: Есть ли разница: по Иванову и по мнению Иванова? Или в соответствии с позицией Иванова? И как зависят от этого знаки? Я бы поставила запятую, если по Иванову = по мнению Иванова. Но не могу найти ни подтверждения, ни опровержения в источниках.

Comment: Ну, может, не по мнению", а "по утверждению" или "по данным Иванова". А запятая-то зачем даже в этом случае?

Comment: ВВодное словосочетание, указывающее на источник сообщения.

Comment: А оно требует обособления? Тогда да.

Не знал. И, похоже, вообще не сталкивался. Столько таких текстов перечитал... Рука бы не поднялась.

~~~~~~~
А если по "методу Иванова"? Тут-то уж никак не источник.

Comment: По-моему, Ларf права, здесь усечённая разговорная форма вводной конструкции ***по мнению (кого? чьему?).*** Её вполне можно заменить предложением:  М.А.Иванов считает,.. .  Запятая нужна.

Comment: Так вот нельзя "заменить" получается. См. мой ответ, дополнение.

Comment: Вы смотри́те, от какого слова зависит "по Ххх". В "первая в Европе операция по профессору Преображенскому" -- цельно "операция по профессору" (по методу), в "громадные дозы камфары по Преображенскому" -- цельно "дозы по Преображенскому" (или с малой вероятностью "громадные по Преображенскому"). Цельные словосочетания. "По Ххх, нужно ..." -- конечно, зависит от контекста, но, скорее всего, тут именно "по мнению Ххх, <всё, что идёт далее>", на это намекают слово "нужно" и то, что "по Ххх" идёт в начале. Хотя, возможно, мы просто с Вами мысленно по-разному окончание предложения дорисовываем.

Comment: "А так это стадо животных, у которых по Павлову нужно вырабатывать рефлексы, если уж это так необходимо." -- вот, кстати, отличный пример. Можно ставить и не ставить. Если не ставить -- получается "нужно вырабатывать по методу Павлова", а если ставить -- получается "по мнению Павлова, нужно вырабатывать рефлексы".

Comment: Sasha, зачем мне что-то смотреть?  Вопрос стоит весьма узко, про конретную фразу. Что там может означать это слово? Де-юре оно может относится ко всей фразе или к части. Это ничего не дает. Вопрос именно в том, что оно значит именно тут, в этой фразе при научной речи. Так вот я уверен, что здесь оно означает по методу, а не по мнению. И если по методу, то к чему бы оно ни относилось, смысла в запятой нет и не просматривается. А было бы по мнению, то это ссылка на источник, тоже спорить не о чем. И никаким другим способом это не устанавливается, кроме опыта чтения подобной литературы. Вот все.

Comment: @behemothus, а где Вы увидели про научную речь? Я *допускаю*, что при некоторых продолжениях предложения Вы можете оказаться правы: "По Иванову нужно немедленно закрыть дело!" (дело по Иванову) и "По Иванову нужно в данной ситуации делать операцию, а не по Петрову!" (операцию по Иванову) -- но эти примеры мне кажутся очень уж надуманными (восклицательный знак намекает, что в таком порядка слова говорит, как правило, очень спешащий человек). Но вот более реалистичный пример: "По Иванову, нужно операцию проводить с утра." -- уже, скорее всего, запятая должна быть.

Comment: А вы какую видите, если не научную? Я в быту не сталкивался с выражениями "по Иванову", разве что ироническое. А в медицине - самое обычное дело. Это мне с младых ногтей, увы, известно.

Comment: *"По Иванову нужно немедленно закрыть дело!"* - это вообще не из той оперы. Здесь иной смысл, далекий от нашего, хотя тоже канцелярит дикий.

Answer (score -1):

Да, нужна.

Запятая нужна в случае, когда «по Иванову» относится не к конкретному слову, а ко всему утверждению:

- > Наши страсти и фобии, **по Хоукингу**, тоже можно объяснить умением лучше видеть "голограмму мира сего". [Александр Волков. Миры Стивена Хоукинга // «Знание -- сила», 2003]
- > **По Кеплеру**, архетипы образуют систему, увенчанную Троицей. [Вячеслав Шевченко. Демон науки: Космический кубок // «Знание -- сила», 2003]

Запятая не нужна, если «по Иванову» относится к конкретному слову (глаголу, существительному и т.п.):

- > Я **лупанул** палкой **по Иванову**. [Цитата моя]
- > Я нашёл **оптимальные по Парето** варианты. [Цитата моя]
- > В **спектакле по Чехову** белорусского театра Янки Купалы аскетизм формы был иного, более радикального порядка. <sub>[Спасительная эстафета игры (2004) // «Экран и сцена», 2004.05.06]</sub>
- > **По Мазилову** удалось добиться прекращения **дела**, но три недели в Бутырской тюрьме он всё же отсидел. [Андрей Андреев. Будущее принадлежит нам! (2003) // «Завтра», 2003.08.22]
- > […] отвоевать Обетованную землю - для себя и своих **сородичей по Аврааму** […]. [Рафаил Нудельман. Тайны вечных книг: ученые исследуют Коран // «Знание -- сила», 2003]
- > Не верим "толстопалым" пиарщикам "Единой России", что они― за народ, которому за год до своей предвыборной лжи они навязали смертоносные законы о земле, жилищно-коммунальную реформу и **реорганизацию** РАО ЕЭС **по Чубайсу**. [Александр Проханов. Прокуратура - кастет с программным управлением (2003) // «Завтра», 2003.07.29]
- > Мне всегда нравились женщины старше меня, что, в общем-то, **логично по Фрейду**. [Светлана Ткачева. День влюбленных... (2003) // «100% здоровья», 2003.01.15]
- > **По Шахновскому выходит**, что Иван-дурак сидел себе на печи, пока неведомо кто "воспламенял Сибирь", в советское время мозолистыми руками добыл 2 миллиарда тонн самотлорской нефти, по лежневкам, в три наката, пробивался с тяжёлой техникой через болота под Сургутом, по комсомольской путёвке от первого колышка выстроил в дикой тундре города, промыслы, аэропорты… [Иван-дурак и миллиардер Шахновский (2003) // «Завтра», 2003.08.22]

Обратите внимание, что смысл последних двух предложений тоже сводится к «по чьему-то мнению», но запятые не стоят.

Comment: Здесь нет такого противопоставления. Здесь почти наверняка "по методу Иванова". Могу сослаться только на огромный опыт чтения и написания подобной белиберды, это это именно опыт. "По мнению Иванова" обычно оформляют иначе, с указанием источника.

Comment: @behemothus, честно говоря, я почти со 100% вероятностю вижу именно "по мнению Иванова". Если было бы "по методу Иванова", то (не факт, но скорее всего) "по Ххх" было бы не в начале и вряд ли бы было сказуемым "нужно". Хотя, как я уже говорил в другом комменте ниже, возможно, мы просто с Вами мысленно по-разному окончание предложения дорисовываем.

Comment: Ну вот потому что мы по разному видим, и спор бесполезен. Просто на мой взгляд любой редактор (знающий, не халтурщик) научного издания забракует такую фразу без ссылки на прямой источник этого "мнения". Это как отче наш. А "метод Иванова" обычно понятие самодостаточное. Как "камфара по Преображенскому" в моей цитате из МАБ.