# Оборот "по верованиям (кого-либо)" выделяется запятыми?

Tags: вводные-слова

Интересуют все случаи – когда он находится в начале, середине и в конце предложения. В списках вводных слов "по верованиям" не нахожу.

Дополню вопрос. В первую очередь речь идет, например, о таких контекстах: "По верованиям древних славян покровителем воинов является бог-громовержец Перун" и т. п.

Answer (score 3):

Списки вводных слов не могут быть исчерпывающими. Там всегда есть "и т. д." По всем же признакам "по верованиям" в определенном значении, когда имеется в виду именно источник утверждения, вполне может быть вводным. 
Соответственно, и пунктуация подобно тому, как, например, *"по мнению"*.
Об особенностях пунктуации подобных вводных слов смотрите тут. 
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2
Никаких специальных оговорок на место в предложении тут нет, такие оговорки касаются только окружения вводных слов. Другое дело, что в начале и конце предложения очень часто, гораздо чаще чем в его середине, слова, напоминающие вводные, на самом деле вводными не являются, но это касается большинства вводных, не только "*по верованиям*".

Основная же сложность рассматриваемого случая в том, что "по верованиям" (по вере) вне зависимости от места в предложении часто оказывается совсем не вводной конструкцией.

*Да воздастся каждому по верованиям его!* - здесь "по верованиям" - член предложения с обстоятельственным значениям.
*Каждому, по верованиям Имярекова, воздастся сторицей* - тут очевидное вводное, источник утверждения.

Подобные сложности известны и в отношении большинства других подобных вводных слов и сочетаний ("по мнению", "по желанию", "по соображениям [безопасности] и т. д.), но в нашем случае, боюсь, надо быть особенно осторожным, уж очень легко спутать по причине особенностей употребления.

//--------------

> Дополню вопрос. В первую очередь речь идет, например, о таких контекстах: "По верованиям древних славян покровителем воинов является бог-громовержец Перун" и т. п.

Да, согласен, здесь сложный случай. Можно по-разному трактовать. При таком построении фразы запятая, считаю, факультативна, я бы её не ставил. Здесь нет однозначного толкования, что "по верованиям" является источником данной мысли, и оборот сам по себе недостаточно распространенный, чтобы требовать запятой для однозначности понимания.

Сравните похожие вопросы:

[«По Иванову(,) нужно сделать так...» Нужна ли запятая?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5899)
[Запятая " в связи"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/30693)

Хорошо бы Людмилу услышать, она куда лучше эти вещи понимает.

Answer (score 0):

Полностью с Вами,уважаемый  behemothus, согласна, запятая факультативна, только это всё-таки не вводное сочетание. а обстоятельственный оборот(как  обороты с предлогами БЛАГОДАРЯ,СОГЛАСНО,ВОПРЕКИ) = согласно верованиям древних славян.

"По верованиям древних славян покровителем воинов является бог-громовержец Перун" Если фразовое ударение падает на этот оборот, он не обособляется, если на основное сообщение, а оборот поясняет сообщение, то оборот обособляется. Стоять он может где угодно, но в конце предложения чаще всего не обособляется, так как тогда на него как раз падает фразовое ударение.

В приведённом примере мне такого ударения не видится, я бы всё-таки обособила в качестве пояснения, но это субъективно.

Вот в таких предложениях не обособляется: По итогам года победила команда...

По результатам ... победил... Хотя здесь тоже в значении "согласно..."